# How to list page categories and corresponding post count in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my jekyll site I have 3 categories in a post. I want to show badges for each category and their post count. I used

```
{% for category in page.categories %}
{% unless category == 'index'%}
<a href="/cat/{{category}}">{{category}}{{category.size}}</a>
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

in post layout.
This works,  but post count shows wrong number. I also tried without `unless` statement but not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{category.size}}` counts the number of letters in current category name.

If you want the number of posts in this `category`, the correct syntax is :

`{{ site.categories[category].size }}`